# Replace Lock screen of selected apps like "App Lock" appication

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want develop App Locking application.
So, I create one Auto start service to check every second to selected application package name is launched or not.perform this task by using

**getRunningTasks(1)**  & for some device work this
**am.getRunningAppProcesses()**

So above method returns every second top activity and current process and I  check selected package name if true then start my lock screen.

But it not working properly, first and second time working fine but I check more, then not open my lock screen.(Service is running).

And second problem is,

In some devices not return recently launch application package name, its continuously returns some launcher processes of OS...

I learn some library or example, but library only start lock or pattern screen for all application not particular application(Package name)

So, What is best solution or suggest me any library or example or best service code to working all devices ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getRunningTasks(1) & getRunningAppProcesses() doesn't work in XIOMI devices, Because of customization.

and i get best service to continuously check running process and activities.

https://github.com/jdavis/get-disciplined